# How to install vagrant plugin on Windows 7 without internet connection?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, vagrant, vagrant-plugin

I'm trying to install vagrant-hostmanager plugin on Windows 7 without internet connection.

I have downloaded gem file from rubygems.org and copied to this machine to D:\distr\Vagrant.

Then I move to this folder and run in Command Prompt with Ruby (with Administrator privilegies):

```
vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager --entry-point vagrant-hostmanager-1.8.6.gem
```

And get the following error:

```
Installing the 'vagrant-hostmanager' plugin. This can take a few minutes...
Vagrant failed to load a configured plugin source. This can be caused
by a variety of issues including: transient connectivity issues, proxy
filtering rejecting access to a configured plugin source, or a configured
plugin source not responding correctly. Please review the error message
below to help resolve the issue:

  Errno::ECONNREFUSED: No connection could be made because the target machine ac
tively refused it. - connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://api.rub
ygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Source: https://rubygems.org/
```

I put specs.4.8.gz to his folder too but it didn't help. I also put specs.4.8 to SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY and gem file to GEM PATHS defined in gem environment. It also didn't help.

Versions:

- Windows Enterprise Service Pack 1 (32 bit)
- vagrant_1.9.5.msi
- VirtualBox-5.1.22-115126-Win.exe
- rubygems 2.5.2
- rubyinstaller  2.3.3 (2016-11-21 patchlevel 222) [i386-mingw32]

I also tried with another versions of vagrant and gem: vagrant_1.8.4.msi and vagrant-hostmanager-1.8.5.gem. Result is the same.

Is it possible to install vagrant plugin offline?

Thanks!